# I can't install DotNetNuke, HTTP error 500.21

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

I want to install dotnetnuk, and I did all what the 4 videos for installing dotNetNuke said.... but I still am getting this damn error:

**HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list**

Module  IIS Web Core

Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated

Error Code  0x8007000d

Requested URL   http://www.dnndev.me:80/default.aspx

Physical Path   C:\websites\dnndev.me\default.aspx

Logon Method    Anonymous

Logon User  Anonymous

**Most likely causes:**
1. Managed handler is used; however, ASP.NET is not installed or is not installed completely.
2. There is a typographical error in the configuration for the handler module list.

**Things you can try:**
1. Install ASP.NET if you are using managed handler.
2. Ensure that the handler module's name is specified correctly. Module names are case-sensitive and use the format modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule".

THing that I did for installing DotNetNUke: I installed iis 7.5 (i also tried 8.0 but didn't worked, too). I checked (because it was unchecked) IIS at **Turn Windows Features on or off**, i also selected the feature ASP.NET (whre other features where selected automatically) also I selected windows authentication.

Afte that I googled and found about aspnet_regiis.exe, and I executed it too, but it also didn't worked :(.

I have no idea what to do now!! I really need to install dotnetnuke, but I can't install it on my laptop :(

Please help me someone!

Comment: I had this error and installed .NET 4.5 to solve the problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992029/why-does-dotnetnuke-7-02-give-this-error-during-installation-bad-module-managed/22455478#22455478

Answer (score 5):

You will need to reinstall the .Net 4 framework to fix this issue.

- Open up a comand prompt window with elivated administrator permissions.
- Execute the following command to reinstall the .Net package.
  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
- Then Restart IIS on your local machine.

That should fix you!

Answer (score 0):

You keep saying that you are installing in IIS 7.5 and then trying 8.0, that would mean that you are installing DNN on multiple machines?

Windows 7 uses IIS 7.5
Windows 8 uses IIS 8.0

What is the .NET version that your application pool?

(I am not sure why you keep posting new questions here on Stack Overflow, instead of just responding to your initial questions/answers)

Answer (score 0):

Issue happens when IIS has issue with some tags in web config file, your web config may be referring to a module which is not known for your IIS, IIS may have not had that module installed on it.
For me there was a rewrite tag in web config, and as I have not had URL rewrite installed on my IIS, IIS was not able to understand the rewrite tag, installing URL rewrite module fixed the issue for me.
To check if the rewrite tag is causing the issue, comment it out in your web config file and try browsing to portal.
Below is the mentioned tag in my config file:

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RSS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/RSS" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/rss.aspx" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url=" .... " appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope it helps.
If it was not causing the issue, then check other tags and see if you have them available on IIS.