# Why does DotNetNuke 7.02 give this error during installation: bad module ManagedPipelineHandler

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

(Q) How do I fix DotNetNuke when it gives this error?

Handler "ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

I've installed DotNetNuke using videos provided, see next link:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/515/view/details/dnn-7-0-installation-part-1-file-system-configuration

The last video (part 4) shows how you "configure" DotNetNuke by navigating to the site.  I went to http://www.dnndev.me.  When I did that, however, I got the above error.

Comment: I found that when I installed .NET 4.5 framework from Microsoft (this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653).  The problem went away (was fixed), and I successfully ran the DotNetNuke Installation Wizard, using the link: http://www.dnndev.me.

Comment: I believe that recents DotNetNuke versions use components of "ASP.Net MVC 4" which are provided in the .Net 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user3281336 who suggested **installing .NET 4.5**.
I downloaded .NET 4.5 at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779 and installed it.

**This fixed the problem.**  The web site would not throw an exception.  If it matters, I was accessing www.dnndev.me which is the "default" web site based on one of the DNN installations.

When searching for solutions to this problem "responders trying to help" sometimes said to re-install .NET 4.0, but in my case I didn't try this because I thought the DNN required this.  Later I looked back at my notes on the video (see http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/515/view/details/dnn-7-0-installation-part-1-file-system-configuration) and it says that only .NET 4.0 was required.

None-the-less, I'm up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this error if you don't have the .NET 4 framework installed, even if you already have 4.5 and 4.5.1 installed.  There is no need to re-install 4.5, instead you just might need to install the [.NET 4 Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17851).

Answer (score 0):

Turning on all WCF-Services of NET Framework solved this problem for me.

Windows Features

[image]